# Let R be a commutative ring with identity and $a,b \in R$. Show that if $a$ is nilpotent and idempotent, then $a=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

It makes sense to me that this is the case, however I'm not sure how to prove it.  Just for an example, I thought about $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and for 1 and 2, it didn't matter what power you raised them to, they would never be 0.  Would you do something like supposing that a was nonzero and do a contradiction proof to prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nilpotent means there is some $k$ such that $a^k=0$.  Idempotent means that $a^2=a$.  Now apply the second property repeatedly to the first, and you get $$0=a^k=(a^2)a^{k-2}=(a)a^{k-2}=a^{k-1}=(a^2)a^{k-3}=(a)a^{k-3}=a^{k-2}=\cdots=a^2=a$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $a$ nilpotent means there exists some $n$ so that $a^n=0$.

$a$ idempotent means $a^2=a$.

**Question** If $a^2=a$ what is $a^3$? What about $a^4$? What about $a^n$?